# Проблема к с ключом OpenAI?

Tags: token, openapi, chatgpt-api

Проблема с токеном OPEN AI, или как получить токен GPT4?
Имеется аккаунт с подпиской GPT PLUS.

Выпущенный API токен от 17 марта сего года.

В скрипте, когда указываешь модель gpt-3.5-turbo - все работает хорошо, бот общается.

Но как только вводишь модель gpt-4-turbo-preview - начинаются проблемы.

На балансе OPENAI деньги есть. Уровень личного аккаунта - 1.

Почему и главное как получить доступ к API gpt4?

[image: вот скрин ошибки в терминале.]

Comment: Какие проблемы-то?

Comment: Дополнил скрином...